# Формат времени в (Oracle) и PHP

Tags: php, oracle, дата

Добрый день. 
Есть база Oracle, в ней таблица, один из столбцов - в формате date. 
В php цепляюсь к таблице и выбираю из нее инфу.

```
$conn = oci_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$query_1 = "select max (p.navi_date), p.navi_user
from payments p
where p.pay_date >= trunc(sysdate)
and p.navi_user = 'HAS:WWW:PARDOXT'
group by  p.navi_user
order by 1";
$s_1 = oci_parse($conn, $query_1);
oci_execute($s_1);
oci_fetch_all($s_1, $arr_1);
$o_1 = $arr_1['MAX(P.NAVI_DATE)'];
echo($o_1[0]);
```

в итоге на странице выдается дата в формате 11.06.15 
Как сделать, чтобы ее формат был 11.06.15  14:31:16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DATE columns are returned as strings formatted to the current date
>   format. The default format can be changed with Oracle environment
>   variables such as NLS_LANG or by a previously executed ALTER SESSION
>   SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT command.

[Example #8 oci_fetch_array() with DATE columns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php)

Или явно через `to_char(max(...), 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss')`.

Answer (score 0):

`echo date('d.m.y H:i:s', strtotime($o_1[0]));`

Comment: 11.06.15 11:06:15    - Показывает дубляж даты, а мне время нужен.